# "You can be able to...". vs. "You would/should be able to..."

Tags: modal-verbs, periphrastic-modals

On many online articles/posts, I've seen writer using the sentence "You can be able to...". Is it because the writer is non-English speaker or that use is grammatically correct?

An example would be this [online post](https://www.assistanz.com/steps-to-migrate-users-from-on-premises-active-directory-to-azure/). If in this post, you search "you can able to" you will find at one place author of the article writes:

> Click on All users link and **you can able** to view our local AD users on the list.

I thought the sentence should be: "

> Click on All users link and **you would be able** to view our local AD users on the list.

Or maybe:

> Click on All users link and **you should be able** to view our local AD users on the list.

But, I may be wrong as I'm myself not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are correct; the example sentence has an error.**

"Can able to" is not correct.

In the most straightforward context, I would recommend:

> ...you **will** be able to...

"Could", "would", or "should" introduce some uncertainty. In some cases, such as describing a hypothetical situation, these words would be appropriate. However, in instructions such as here, I hope the writer *knows* what *will* happen when I click a link rather than *supposing* what *should* happen.